# Suitable drafting rules for multi-set repacks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting

For fun we picked up a booster box of multi-set repacks at our LGS (really cheap). Our intention was drafting, but we found that since they are multi-set the cards lack the synergies when drafting from a single block, plus the odds of getting to of the same card are close to zero.

I am new to drafting, so curious if there is a better format to play with multi-set repacks? Maybe just constructed (6 boosters to build a deck from)? Maybe a specific variation of drafting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drafting with multi packs or with packs from all different blocks works just fine you just need to aim for certain archtypes (control, aggro, ect) as opposed to specific strategies (such as human tribal) and you'll have more success. In my experience the only rule you really need to have outside of regular draft rules is to ban the unsets. Sealed also works well. Same advice (archtype over specific strategy) applies though you have a bit more leeway since you can see everything you have from the get go.

Comment: Also, take a look for tips on creating a Cube draft. They're very popular, and often contain dozens of sets worth of cards in them.